# How to lock an image to the background on Tkinter? (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two images, a post and a background. When i scroll up and down the page this is the result: https://youtu.be/3j3QIc7z6hQ

I want the post to be attached to the background. Is there any method to do this?

I'm using this code to scroll up and down the program:

```py
def on_mousewheel(event):
    shift = (event.state & 0x1) != 0
    scroll = -1 if event.delta > 0 else 1
    if shift:
        canvas.xview_scroll(scroll, "units")
    else:
        canvas.yview_scroll(scroll, "units")

canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", on_mousewheel)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Frame in frame. Make the background frame slightly larger than the front frame and then scroll them base on the background frame.

Comment: i haven't created any Frames, only Canvas. Here's the entire script: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1odExg9pZvlfBPfPc6UyIKBubrdiFi5Sq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Put the frames on the canvis.

Comment: What do you mean by "Put the frames"?

Comment: You can add widgets to a canvas. So you create a set of frames for the look you want with your background and image then you place them in the canvas to allow for the canvas to scroll the widget. There are many post about scrolling widgets on this site.